# How to prioritize your snippets in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I am using Atom for over year now and recently I have started to write my own snippets but I am struggling with using them properly. Snippets from Atom packages are showed in autocomplete panel before mine. Is there any option to prioritize your custom snippets in Atom?

e.g: I have the custom snippet for console.log statement and I would like to have it as the first choice in autocomplete panel.

[image: Example of]

My colleagues are using vs-code and there is the option for doing that:

```
“editor.snippetSuggestions”: “top”
```

I was looking for a similar solution in Atom's doc but without success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: nope, I switched to VS Code a few weeks after posting this.